# yum error in PREUN scriptlet when removing packages

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

Trying to uninstall `zarafa` mail server.

I use `yum list installed` to view the already installed packages.

After which I use `yum erase zarafa*`

It picks up all the packages but returns:

```
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package zarafa-dagent
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package zarafa-gateway
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package zarafa-monitor
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package zarafa-server
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package zarafa-spooler
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package zarafa-ical
zarafa-ical-7.1.9-1.el6.i686 was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : zarafa-ical-7.1.9-1.el6.i686                                                                                                                                                1/6 
zarafa-spooler-7.1.9-1.el6.i686 was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : zarafa-spooler-7.1.9-1.el6.i686                                                                                                                                             2/6 
zarafa-server-7.1.9-1.el6.i686 was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : zarafa-server-7.1.9-1.el6.i686                                                                                                                                              3/6 
zarafa-monitor-7.1.9-1.el6.i686 was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : zarafa-monitor-7.1.9-1.el6.i686                                                                                                                                             4/6 
zarafa-gateway-7.1.9-1.el6.i686 was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : zarafa-gateway-7.1.9-1.el6.i686                                                                                                                                             5/6 
zarafa-dagent-7.1.9-1.el6.i686 was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : zarafa-dagent-7.1.9-1.el6.i686                                                                                                                                              6/6 

Failed:
  zarafa-dagent.i686 0:7.1.9-1.el6      zarafa-gateway.i686 0:7.1.9-1.el6     zarafa-ical.i686 0:7.1.9-1.el6     zarafa-monitor.i686 0:7.1.9-1.el6     zarafa-server.i686 0:7.1.9-1.el6    
  zarafa-spooler.i686 0:7.1.9-1.el6
```

Comment: searched for `Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package ddclient
` and came here - Thanks.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It seems like somehow yum cached data and the rpm database got out of sync with each other I guess.
Try running the next commands:

```
su -c 'yum clean all && rpm --rebuilddb'
su -c 'package-cleanup --problems'
```

Then run:

```
su -c 'yum erase zarafa*'
```

Edit #1:
Try running the next command:

```
# su -c 'yum --setopt=tsflags=noscripts remove zarafa*'
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
# su -c 'rpm -e --noscripts zarafa*'
```

Comment: good try, but it still failed

Comment: Yes, exactly the same

Comment: And the command from my Edit #1?

Comment: `yum --setopt=tsflags=noscripts remove <pkgname>` worked for me

Comment: Where are the tsflags defined? I can't seem to find good documentation for them.

Comment: @sergio tsflags are part of the yum.conf file https://jsmith.fedorapeople.org/drafts/SMG/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch06s22.html

Comment: This worked for me very well.

Answer (score 14):

I did a `rpm -ql <packagename>` to see the package original contents.

manually deleted any left over file.

ran yum with the noscripts flag as described above, so the script doesn't fail.

```
yum --setopt=tsflags=noscripts remove <packagename>
```